# Не работает import после транспиляции JSX в JS (ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, babel

Начал изучать React параллельно с JS. В своем коде использую препроцессор JSX. Для того, чтобы браузер смог воспринимать код на JSX, его надо преобразовать в обычный JS. В качестве транспайлера использую Babel с пресетом react: `npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev`. Саму транспиляцию выполняю: `babel test.js -o test2.js --presets react`. В итоге получаю:

**test.js**

```
import btnName from './name.js';

class MainPage extends React.Component {

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>{btnName}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MainPage />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**name.js**

```
export btnName = "button";
```

**test2.js**

```
import btnName from './name.js';

class MainPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            React.createElement(
                'button',
                null,
                btnName
            )
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MainPage, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

После подключения test2.js к index.html не происходит ничего. Но стоит убрать import и заменить btnName в методе render на обычную строку, то все становиться нормально. С чем это связано? Как все-таки использовать import?

Comment: Могу заблуждаться, но, возможно, нужно `export btnName = "button"` заменить на `export const btnName = "button"`

Comment: @smellyshovel Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [докам мозилы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax), нужно экспортировать так: `export const btnName = "button"`.
Но, лично у меня, на такую конструкцию Chrome ругается, что нет экспорта "default" из модуля.

А вот следующая работает нормально:

```
const btnName = "button";

export default btnName;
```

Но Google, к примеру, [не рекомендует](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide#file-es6-modules) пока использовать ES6 модули, т.к. их семантика не финализирована.

Comment: Ни то, ни другое не помогло.

Comment: @Code, а в консоли браузера ошибки есть? Может вы скрипт неверно вообще подключаете? Для корректной работы тега у `scrypt` надо указывать  `type="module"`, вместо `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Действительно, так заработало. Правда при импорте еще { btnName } пришлось добавить. Это нужно всегда указывать скриптам, где происходит импорт (я про type)?

Comment: Если коротко - да. А вообще, советую поскать инфу про поддержку ES6 браузерами. Там не все так радужно, насколько я помню.

Comment: @RAMe0, в вопросе явно указано, что используется сборщик, обычно сборщики сами собирают модули и на уровне браузера в коде их уже нет, поэтому непонятен совет смотреть про поддержку модулей браузерами, если в конечном коде их нет.

Comment: @Grundy, ну, мой совет решил проблему автора, так что не вижу с этим проблем. Я с чистым babel дела не имею, посмотрел на приведенный в вопросе результат его раоботы и посоветовал исходя из него. Возможно, бэйбл и умеет собирать модули, я не в курсе, просто у меня за это отвечает browserify.

Comment: @RAMe0, модули в том числе. Кстати интересна дата style guide, потому что описание модулей уже включено в спецификацию.

Comment: @Grundy, не могли бы вы, в таком случае, добавить ответ, с описанием того, как нужно сконфигурировать babel, для того чтобы он соборку делал? Думаю, это будет полезно.

Comment: @RAMe0, не мог бы :-) он вообще должен это по умолчанию делать и в принципе проблема у автора не с модулями как таковыми, а тем, что он не правильно их использует: инпортирует/экспортирует